# JQuery - File attributes

Tags: jquery, file, attr

Trying to access file attributes from an input field after a file is selected.
Tried this but get the error 'file not defined'

```
var file = $("#uploadedfile").prop("files")[0];
var fileName = file.fileName;
var fileSize = file.fileSize;
alert("Uploading: "+fileName+" @ "+fileSize+"bytes");
```

Comment: did u try change prop for attr ?

Comment: have you done any debugging? The error suggests that there is something wrong with `$("#uploadedfile").prop("files")[0];`.

Comment: does your browser support access?

Comment: 1) Tried using attr, same results
2) Only error message I get is 'file is not defined'
3) I am using Mac Firefox 8.0.1, so how would I be able to check if it supports access?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If `#uploadedfile` is an input with type "file" :

```
var file = $("#uploadedfile")[0].files[0];
var fileName = file.name;
var fileSize = file.size;
alert("Uploading: "+fileName+" @ "+fileSize+"bytes");
```

Normally this would fire on the change event, like so:

```
$("#uploadedfile").on("change", function(){
   var file = this.files[0],
       fileName = file.name,
       fileSize = file.size;
   alert("Uploading: "+fileName+" @ "+fileSize+"bytes");
   CustomFileHandlingFunction(file);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/eq3Qv/)

Comment: Get this error still: 
$(this).files is undefined
[Break On This Error] (85 out of range 4)

Comment: Are you doing this on the change event, after a file has been added, so there actually is a file to get the filename from, and have you tried David's example fiddle in his answer to see if the file you select is logged in the console of your browser.

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a files property. try `$("#uploadedfile")[0].files[0]` and `$(this)[0].files[0]` or `this.files[0]`, however, it will have the exact same effect as the code in the question. I think this is simply a question of browser support.

Comment: This should work in Firefox as well, this [site](http://base64img.com/#encode) uses the exact same code, and it works just fine in Firefox, gets the filename and size without a hitch.

Comment: Yeah its a browser issue. Doesnt work in firefox for me but works in safari.

Comment: @KevinB - I've added a fiddle that should work in all browsers.

Comment: I modified your fiddle to one that doesn't throw an error in IE, since we all know IE is slow to implement cool stuff like this, >.<. http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/eq3Qv/1/

Comment: Good catch Kevin, did'nt really think of that. Seems the problem was just a little typo from @JamesHickman, that for some reason works in webkit but not in Firefox. Problem solved :-)

Comment: @baybora.oren - IE9 does'nt support the HTML5 File API at all, so no, this does not work in IE9 ?

Comment: I may get `$(...)[0].files[0] is undefined` here when the element is not in form. Maybe add some pre-check around it to avoid that error in Firefox.

Comment: @Roland - Then you'd wrap the entire function in something like `if ($("#el").length) ...`

Answer (score 8):

```
<form id = "uploadForm" name = "uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="uploadFile">Upload Your File</label>
     <input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile">                  
</form>
<script>
    $('#uploadFile').change(function(){
        var fileName = this.files[0].name;
        var fileSize = this.files[0].size;
        var fileType = this.files[0].type;
        alert('FileName : ' + fileName + '\nFileSize : ' + fileSize + ' bytes');
    });
</script>
```

**Note:** 
To get the uploading file name means then use jquery val() method.

**For Ex:**

```
var fileName = $('#uploadFile').val();
```

I checked this above code before post, it works perfectly.!

Answer (score 2):

To get the filenames, use:

```
var files = document.getElementById('inputElementID').files;
```

Using jQuery (since you already are) you can adapt this to the following:

```
$('input[type="file"][multiple]').change(
    function(e){
        var files = this.files;
        for (i=0;i<files.length;i++){
            console.log(files[i].fileName + ' (' + files[i].fileSize + ').');
        }
        return false;
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ytf3M/1/).

Comment: This works great in chrome, however in firefox i get undefined (undefined), this is going to simply be a question of browser support.

Answer (score 1):

Just try

```
var file = $("#uploadedfile").prop("files")[0];
var fileName = file.name;
var fileSize = file.size;
alert("Uploading: "+fileName+" @ "+fileSize+"bytes");
```

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The `input.files` attribute is an HTML5 feature. That's why some browsers din't return anything.
Simply add a fallback to the plain old `input.value` (string) if `files` doesn't exist.

reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/common-input-element-apis.html#dom-input-files