# Javascript .files[0] attribute in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, multipartform-data

Is there an equivalent to this statement in jQuery?

```
var value = document.getElementById(id).files[0];
```

Using the standard jQuery selectors with .files[0] appended doesn't appear to work, and I can't find an equivalent jQuery command to .files. Any suggestions?

I'm using this to retrieve the file from an input type='file' form element.

Comment: I am afraid there isn't for now.

Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436315/jquery-file-attributes) post.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$('#id').get(0).files[0]
```

get(0) return DOM element

Comment: It just an fyi so you can refine your answer. Edit and I will upvote :)

Comment: Thanks! I totally forgot about .get(0).