# uploading image on submit through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to submit the file (image) to php with ajax using this. But all tutorials and references i saw were assigning file to variable with `onchange` event.

But I want to send this request when user clicks submit.
But it keeps giving error: `cannot read property 0 of undefined`.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#btn").on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var i=new FormData();
        var p=$("#img").files[0];//keep getting error here says "cannot read Property 0 of undefined"
        i.append('image',p);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'uploaded.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'formdata',
            data: i,
            success:function (response){
                console.log(response);
            }
        })
    });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="submit" type="POST"  action="">
        <input type="file" id="img" >
        <input type="submit" id="btn">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just replace 4th statement with var p=$("#img")[0].files[0];

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload file asynchronously you need to use IFRAME.

For jquery exist very usable plugin [AjaxFIleUpload](https://github.com/jfeldstein/jQuery.AjaxFileUpload.js)

Example:

```
-- Use as little as --

    $('#one-specific-file').ajaxfileupload({
      'action': '/upload.php'
    });

-- or as much as --

    $('input[type="file"]').ajaxfileupload({
      'action': '/upload.php',
      'params': {
        'extra': 'info'
      },
      'onComplete': function(response) {
        console.log('custom handler for file:');
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
      },
      'onStart': function() {
        if(weWantedTo) return false; // cancels upload
      },
      'onCancel': function() {
        console.log('no file selected');
      }
    });
```

Comment: its too general..i want something much personalized because not only i need to send image some extra variables are also needed to be send

Answer (score 0):

You can add this

```
var p = file = $("#img")[0].files[0];
var fileName = file.name;
var fileSize = file.size;
alert("Uploading: "+fileName+" @ "+fileSize+"bytes");
```

taken from this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436315/jquery-file-attributes)

Comment: But now a new error started at $.ajax line..saying "Illegal Invocation"

Comment: like Alexander.Shtanko said, you'll need to use an iframe, the illegal part cames out from jquery not been allowed to access your system, it's a security issue

Comment: give some link for reference on how to use iframe